# Clearing Selected Features in ArcMap using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layers, select

How do I clear any selected features using ArcPy, which may cause an error if I run my tool and the user has made a selection on that layer or table view.

I need something that runs ("CLEAR_SELECTION") before I use something like:

```
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(Table, " \"Name\" LIKE 'Albert%' ", "", "Name;")
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is the help document covering the function in question:  [Select Layer by Attribute (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000071000000)

I think this is how you would implement it:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Table, "CLEAR_SELECTION")
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(Table, " \"Name\" LIKE 'Albert%' ", "", "Name;")
```

As an aside, there are a lot of helpful examples of how to use the various toolbox tools, and their python implementations on the ArcGIS Desktop Help Site in the [Professional Library](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_s_in_the_Professional_Library/00r900000092000000/).  A quick search there will often yield an answer faster than on GIS SE.